# remove 2nd line of output using awk

Tags: awk

I have the following output:

```
Filename:xxxxxxxx
date: 2014/12/24 14:46:41;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +210 -206
date: 2014/11/18 21:00:43;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +617 -594
revision 1.23
```

If i see the 2 date: in the output I want to remove that entire line from the output. 2nd line is there if the dev actually added a bug number and explanation, but in many older checkins they didn't so it grabs the date from the checkin before that. I'd like to have awk remove any 2nd occurance of date: along with the entire line of text behind it.

so im doing a grep date|awk 'FNR <3' to get the text i want, but i'd like to either punt it thru awk again to scrub the 2nd date line out or combine it into one awk command if at all possible.

thanks!

Comment: Are more than two date lines possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and an input file with the name `foo`

```
awk '! /^date/ {print} /^date/ && ! a {a=1; print}' foo
```

Output

```
Filename:xxxxxxxx
date: 2014/12/24 14:46:41;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +210 -206
revision 1.23
```

---

If you have more than one block of `Filename` … `revision` in one file, e.g.

```
Filename:xxxxxxxx
date: 2014/12/24 14:46:41;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +210 -206
date: 2014/11/18 21:00:43;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +617 -594
revision 1.23
Filename:xxxxxxxx
date: 2014/12/24 14:46:41;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +210 -206
date: 2014/11/18 21:00:43;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +617 -594
revision 1.23
```

you should use

```
awk '! /^date/ {a=0; print} /^date/ && ! a {a=1; print}' foo
```

to get

```
Filename:xxxxxxxx
date: 2014/12/24 14:46:41;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +210 -206
revision 1.23
Filename:xxxxxxxx
date: 2014/12/24 14:46:41;  author: xxxxx;  state: Exp;  lines: +210 -206
revision 1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asks specifically for an AWK solution, however here's an alternative using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^date/){$x ne 0?$x=0:next}print' in
```

- `if(/^date/){[...]}`: if the current line starts with a `date` string, executes the statements contained in `[...]`;
- `$x ne 0?$x=0:next`: if `x` is not equal to 0, sets `x` to 0; otherwise moves to the next line;
- `print`: prints the current line